# How to loop over an array within a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Very new to JavaScript objects, so I am not to sure how to go about doing this.

Within my object, I have an array called `myArray`. I am attempting to loop over it to print out everything on the page. Usually there is a a lot more data within the object, but it has been removed for this example.

**This is my object:**

```
var data = [
    {
        myArray:
        {
            name: 'name1',
            code: 'code1',
            data: {
                date: '20-Apr-2014',
                signal: 'signal1'
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'name2',
            code: 'code2',
            data: {
                date: '21-Apr-2014',
                signal: 'signal2'
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**This is my iteration code:**

```
var arrayLength = data.myArray.length - 1;
for (var i = 0; i <= arrayLength; i++) {
    var name = data.myArray[i].name;
    console.log(name);
}
```

My code above should produce the results in the console `name1` and `name2`. However, I am getting an error of `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

How can I change my above code to do this?

Comment: Your json is not valid... http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @superUntitled It's invalid, but it also isn't JSON. [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or JSLint would be more fitting suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object should use brackets for the array:

```
var data = {
    myArray: [
    {
        name: 'name1',
        code: 'code1',
        data: {
            date: '20-Apr-2014',
            signal: 'signal1'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'name2',
        code: 'code2',
        data: {
            date: '21-Apr-2014',
            signal: 'signal2'
        }
    }
    ]
}
```

I've also removed the outermost brackets, since it would appear from your question that your intent was to have a single array inside an object, and not an array of arrays.

With the object above, your iteration code will work fine.